# ViewにMenuを実装したいです｡

Tags: android

http://3g28wn33sno63ljjq514qr87.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/YouTube-Android-Update-1.png

上の画像の､リスト項目の右上に3つの点が書かれています｡そこをタッチすると､その下､または上にメニューが表示されます｡
このようにActionBarやToolbarではない場所にMenuを実装するにはどうしたら良いのでしょうか｡
よろしくおねがいします｡

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[PopupMenu](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/PopupMenu.html) を使えば良いのではないでしょうか。